# Is there a way to use `someButton.enabled = NO;` without dimming the custom image UIButton?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uibutton

Is there a way to use `someButton.enabled = NO;` without dimming the custom image of the `UIButton`?

I would like it to change images without the iOS enabled=no effect.

Comment: From a human interface standpoint, it is certainly best to indicate _somehow_ that the button is disabled.

Comment: set image for button by a expecific state. check out this reference, should be until. From Apple docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of setting the image of the disabled button to be equal to the image when the button is enabled:

```
UIImage* image=[button imageForState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage: image forState: UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Answer (score 2):

See `-[UIButton setAdjustsImageWhenDisabled:]`. I believe it will do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can set the "skin" of the button for the `Normal` state and the `Disabled` state to the same image:

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalState"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normalState"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```